# What is the consequence of no Medium (Tablet?) form factor allowed for Lightning console apps?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, form-factor

I'm looking at how a Lightning app written by a third party handles desktop/tablet/mobile devices and adding `<formFactors>Medium</formFactors>` here (that AFAIK corresponds to a tablet):

```
<CustomApplication ...>
    ...
    <formFactors>Small</formFactors>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    ...
    <navType>Console</navType>
    ...
</CustomApplication>
```

results in this clear error message:

> FormFactors must be either Large or Small for Lightning console apps

But what I haven't found is the consequence of this i.e. what happens for this app on a "Medium" device i.e. a tablet? Does it just refuse to display at all?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm) says:

> For example, in this code snippet, the region has a large width to render in when the template is rendered on a large form factor. The region has a small width to render in when the template is rendered on a medium form factor.

Mind you, this is talking about Lightning Page Templates, but the same principles apply here. A Medium form factor gets the same sizes as a Small form factor. Only when you get to the Large form factor do you scale up to the Large size.

There's an [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000leqCQAQ) to allow us to have Medium as its own form factor, which would be nice (make sure you vote).

Comment: Very helpful. I think the summary in my context (assuming the concept transfers) where Medium can't be nominated is that both the phone and the tablet use the small configuration.